# Instanced objects are not the same

Tags: particles, instances

I have a bunch of rocks made with the rock generator add on which I scattered accross a landscape using a particle system. I then made the particle instances real and instanced them on another plane so that the particle system would loop. However the shape of the rocks is changing randomly every 2 instances. I also cannot apply transforms to the rocks because it throws a multi users error for some reason, that may be why.

Is there a better way to array a particle system so that it loops?

Blend file(wetransfer since giantcow doesn't work for me): https://we.tl/t-ky7CiTA2M4

As you can see the displacement changes accross instances, but if I manually move the original rock the displacement remains the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are displacement modifiers of generated rock set to local?

Comment: @AlexanderBicukow yes. I've added a link to the blend in case you want to take a look.